# Rails 4 before_update condition on individual columns SQL overhead

Tags: ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, model, conditional-statements

tI have a Player model in my rails app. 2 columns I am evaluating are highestLevel and highestScore.  This is a stats tracking for a single player across multiple profiles, so there is the possibility that either of these values coming in could be lower than the current value in the db.  Therefore I only wish it update a particular column IF the incoming posted value is greater than the one in the DB.  Reading up on some of the built in validation options, I was not able to get any to work as I intended, however, I was able to write my own validations which work, but at the cost of calling Player.find(id) within the model. Is there a way around this so that my Player.update() does not result in both and UPDATE and SELECT?

Here is my model:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  #validates_numericality_of :highestLevel, greater_than: Proc.new { |r| r.highestLevel }
  #validates_numericality_of :highestScore, greater_than: Proc.new { |r| r.highestScore }

  before_update :player_record, :eval_highestLevel, :eval_highestScore

  # TODO: Find a more effective way to handle update evaluations with less SQL overhead
  private
    def eval_highestLevel
      # if highestLevel in DB has higher value , update the value
      if @p.highestLevel > self.highestLevel
        self.highestLevel = @p.highestLevel
      end
    end

    def eval_highestScore
      # if record in DB has higher value , update the value
      if @p.highestScore > self.highestScore
        self.highestScore = @p.highestScore
      end
    end

    def player_record
      @p = Player.find(id)
    end
end
```

Any ideas on how to make this more efficient, or should I leave it alone?  I'm always looking for the bigger and better mouse trap for Rails 4.x

Comment: Wouldn't `@p` and `self` be the same thing? Or is it that lots of things are messing with `highestScore` behind your back so you need to pull it out of the database to see if you need to change it? If so then the correct solution would be put that logic into the database using a trigger to make it easier to avoid race conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails automatically defines helpers to get the previous value of an attribute when the attribute has changed but the record hasn't been persisted yet. They're named e.g. `attribute name_was`, so in this case `Player#highestLevel_was` and `highestScore_was`:

```
def eval_highestLevel
  # if highestLevel in DB has higher value , update the value
  if self.highestLevel_was > self.highestLevel
    self.highestLevel = @p.highestLevel
  end
end
```

This is documented in [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html). A number of other useful methods are defined, for example:

- `attribute_name_changed?` returns `true` if the attribute has changed.
- `attribute_name_change` returns an array with two elements, the old value and the new value.

Armed with this knowledge we can actually simplify your callbacks a lot:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :ensure_highestLevel, if: :highestLevel_changed?
  before_update :ensure_highestScore, if: :highestLevel_changed?

  protected
  def ensure_highestLevel
    self.highestLevel = self.highestLevel_change.compact.max
  end

  def ensure_highestScore
    self.highestScore = self.highestScore_change.compact.max
  end
end
```

Since `self.highestScore_change` will be an array of two numbers, we can call `max` to get the higher one. We use `Array#compact` because if either the old value or the new value is `nil` we'd get an error (`[nil,1].max # => ArgumentError: comparison of NilClass with 1 failed`). `compact` removes any `nil`s from the array first.

Or even more succinctly:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update ->{ highestLevel = highestLevel_change.compact.max },
    if: :highestLevel_changed?

  before_update ->{ highestScore = highestScore_change.compact.max },
    if: :highestScore_changed?
end
```